# Remove only one the smallest value in an array. JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is the task.
Given an array of integers, remove the smallest value. Do not mutate the original array/list. If there are multiple elements with the same value, remove the one with a lower index. If you get an empty array/list, return an empty array/list.
Don't change the order of the elements that are left.

Here is the code, which removes all the smallest values.

```
function smallest(arr) {
  return arr.filter((it) => it !== Math.min.apply(null, arr)) 
}
```

And here is the code, which keeps all duplicates.

```
const aa = arr.filter((it,index) => arr.indexOf(it) !== index)
```

I want to combine them somehow to get the result but still couldn't do it. 
Is it possible to do or need to use another way? 
Maybe you know how to solve it with reduce?

Answer (score 5):

Find the smallest, find it's index, filter out the item in that index:

```js
function removeSmallest(arr) {
  const smallest = Math.min(...arr);
  const index = arr.indexOf(smallest);
  
  return arr.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
}

const result = removeSmallest([2, 1, 5, -10, 4, -10, 2])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOf()` to get the index of the smallest element. Then use `slice()` to get everything before and after that index, and combine them with `concat()`

```js
const arr = [10, 3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 1, 6, 8];
const smallest = Math.min(...arr);
const smallestIndex = arr.indexOf(smallest);
const newArr = arr.slice(0, smallestIndex).concat(arr.slice(smallestIndex+1));
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeSmallest(numbers) {
    let indexOfMin = numbers.indexOf(Math.min(...numbers));
    return [...numbers.slice(0, indexOfMin), ...numbers.slice(indexOfMin + 1)];
}
```